# GWT-Drag and Drop for draggable Viewport

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, drag-and-drop, uibinder

I use [GWT-dnd](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/) to make a viewport draggable. A viewport is fixed size window that shows a part of a larger map. As illustrated in the following image:

[image]

I followed this post: [Move ViewPort of Element Map in GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433813/move-viewport-of-element-map-in-gwt) which works fine, but I could not get it get to work with GWT-dnd. GWT-dnd.

I created the following simple scenario:

[image]

My problem is that I could GWT-dnd make working only if the drag panel is smaller than the drop panel. In my case the map (canvas), which is the yellow box, is much bigger than the viewport. If I make the viewport as the drop area and the map draggable then it does not work. When I try to drag the map it will be adjusted by one boundary of the viewport and that's it.

What is want is the following: When is drag the map (the part of the map that is visible in the viewport) than the position of the map should change. For example when I drag the map down I get what I show in the following image:

[image]

What the user actually sees is the following:

[image]

Here is what I did in my ScreenView.ui.xml file:

```
    <g:AbsolutePanel ui:field="viewport" addStyleNames="{resources.screenCss.viewportContainer}">
        <g:FocusPanel ui:field="canvasFocus"
                        addStyleNames="{resources.screenCss.focusPanel}">
            <g:AbsolutePanel ui:field="canvas"
                        addStyleNames="{resources.screenCss.canvas}">

                    <g:HTMLPanel  addStyleNames="{resources.screenCss.mapContainer}">

                        <g:FlowPanel ui:field="test1" addStyleNames="{resources.screenCss.test1}">
                            <g:HTML>test1</g:HTML>
                        </g:FlowPanel>

                        <g:FlowPanel ui:field="test2" addStyleNames="{resources.screenCss.test2}">
                            <g:HTML>test2</g:HTML>
                        </g:FlowPanel>

                    </g:HTMLPanel>


            </g:AbsolutePanel>
        </g:FocusPanel>
    </g:AbsolutePanel>
```

In my ScreeView.java I do:

```
@UiField
AbsolutePanel viewport;

@UiField
AbsolutePanel canvas;

@UiField
FlowPanel test1;

private PickupDragController dragController;
private DropController dropController;

    // create drag controller
dragController = new PickupDragController(viewport, true);

    // create drop controller 
    dropController = new AbsolutePositionDropController(canvas);
    dragController.registerDropController(dropController);

    // make test1 draggable
    FocusPanel focusPanel = new FocusPanel();
focusPanel.addStyleName(resources.screenCss().noteFocusPanel());
test1.add(focusPanel);
    canvas.add(test1);
    dragController.makeDraggable(test1, focusPanel);
```

Now I have a red rectangle draggable.

**How can I make my map (canvas) draggable?**

I created a project with the code here: https://github.com/confile/test5

Answer (score 2):

You can try a different layering:

layer 0: canvas not dragable (base frame constraining the view port)

layer 1: the map - draggable (with sides snapping to the canvas layer)

layer 2: the view port - draggable (via some handle or via its frame constrained to canvas area)

Comment: do you have any idea?

Comment: Should I make an new demo or can you fix it?

Comment: I updated the sample project now it is working fine can you try: https://github.com/confile/test5

Comment: project is reporting testgwp/test missing (on Java Build Path)

Comment: Even so, the project runs, but strangely enough your objects don't show even though the Divs and style is there...

Comment: which gwt-dnd sample project or base project did you use ?

Comment: I did not use a sample. Change it if you will. Or should I make a new project?

Comment: I managed to go over all of the settings and have it run without exceptions. will test the dnd and write back when possible...